# Re-calibrate an existing regression model

Tags: python, pandas, regression

I have a pandas dataframe shown below (snapshot), I am trying to re-calibrate a regression equation.
`Loss = (EXP(-1.01 + (-0.08 x mob)) x Price)`
I wanted to fit  regression on the new data available but not sure how I can input the new coefficients into the existing equation. Loss is my target variable ; mob and price are my independent variables.

For e.g. : `New Loss equation = (EXP(b1 + (b2 x mob)) x Price)` . Please let me know how to achieve this ? , thanks in advance

```
Months     RefID     Price   Loss    mob
1/11/2019  100        4.00    3.43    2.00          
1/11/2019  101        10.00   8.58    3.00          
1/11/2019  102        20.00   17.16   1.00         
1/12/2019  100        44.00   37.74   3.00         
1/12/2019  101        66.00   56.61   4.00         
1/12/2019  102        7.00    6.00    2.00          
1/12/2019  103        9.00    7.72    1.00          
...
```

I think the person who built the model has used interaction and used linear regression but I am not sure, I am doing the below but not sure if this is the correct approach:

```
X = stage2[["Price" , "Interact_Price_mob"]] # Interact_Price_mob = Price*mob
y= stage2[["Loss"]]
reg = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(X,y)
print(reg.coef_)
```

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Is it on the math part or the programming part?

Comment: Do you have a typo in your question? Should it say `New Loss equation = (EXP(b1 + (b2 x mob)) x Price)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two choices about how to do the regression. One is to convert the exponential to a linear equation and solve with linear regression. (Note that your equation can be rewritten as `log(loss/price) = b1 + b2 * mob`, if you are unsure how, review your logarithm rules and prove it to yourself.) The other is to do a nonlinear least squares fit to the exponential. For both, I use `scipy` below. For the exponential: [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit). For the linear: [`scipy.polyfit` with a first-order polynomial](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/LinearRegression.html). Note that there are other tools to do a linear regression (including from first principles) and this is likely not the most efficient, though I haven't checked.

The values are just the ones in your example above, so it's a very small data set but good enough for demonstration.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import polyfit 

# mob, price, and loss defined from values given above

# nonlinear least squares fit
def f(x, b1, b2):
    mob = x[0,:]
    price = x[1,:]
    return(np.exp(b1 + b2 * mob) * price)

x = np.array([mob, price])
b, cov = curve_fit(f, xdata = x, ydata = loss)

# linear regression (polynomial fit of order 1)
(b2, b1) = polyfit(mob, np.log(loss/price), 1)

# Comparison
print('Regression\tb1\t\t\tb2')
print(f'Linear\t\t{b1}\t{b2}')
print(f'Exponential\t{b[0]}\t{b[1]}')
```

```
Regression      b1                      b2
Linear          -0.15350910350019625    1.7615305296685054e-06
Exponential     -0.15324071098380723    -6.040694002336243e-05
```

[image: fit comparison]

These are clearly similar but not identical. This is because both methods use a least squares fit but on different metrics.

- In the linear regression, a difference between a data point of 1 and a prediction of 2 has the same weight as the difference between a data point of 10 and a prediction of 20 because we have taken a logarithm of your actual equation and `log(2)-log(1) = log(2/1) = log(20/10) = log(20)-log(10)`.
- In the exponential regression, a difference between a data point of 1 and a prediction of 2 has the same weight as the difference between a data point of 10 and a prediction of 11.

Depending on your application and the range in values of your dataset, this difference could be important and one choice may be better than the other. In your case, I would want to try to reproduce the results that were used previously and see if either regression model does so, then decide if you simply want to update parameters or also update the regression model used.

Comment: First of all , Legend ! thank you so much for taking your time to explain the approaches. Answer Upvoted. I have tried both the cases and seems like with polyfit() method, I am coming up with nan's in my coefficients and with the exponential one I am getting similar coefficients with the older dataset on which the model is built

Comment: Ah - my guess is that you have a negative loss value somewhere as log of a negative number is nan. (A 0 price value would give a divide by 0 error.)

Comment: I did the transformation and removed the noise and I am getting similar results using both approaches.